# GitHub updates were rejected because the tip of current branch is behind its remote counterpart

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I suppose I get the basics of GitHub - I understand initializing  a repository on my local machine, committing, pushing, pulling, cloning, etc.  But when it comes to branches and such, I am completely lost.

Right now I'm trying to push my most recent version of a project, and I can't.  The following things are true:

1. the repository on the website is mine and I am the only collaborator on this project;
2. this site is my portfolio.  I've only ever created the master branch, but there is a "developing" branch that I did not create, but I assume that is default when you create a portfolio on GitHub Pages.
3. I've pushed to this project several times before, and it is always a problem.

As I said, I'm trying to push my most recent version.  Here is what happens:

I check the branch that I'm in, and it says I'm in "master".  I add, commit, and try to push through my terminal.  It asks me for my username and password, I put them in, and it returns:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/...(my portfolio      address)...io.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So then I tried to pull, and received this:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

   git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

  git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

I don't understand this.  What exactly does it mean to be behind a branch?  I thought I understood that but clearly I don't.  And even if I got it, how can my own branch be behind itself?  I've never pushed to any other branch!

Comment: How did you pull?  Show us the _exact_ syntax you used.  Also, is anyone else sharing this branch?  This could explain how you got "behind" your own branch.

Comment: No one is sharing this branch.  I'm the only one on it.  I pushed by the following:  $git add .   git commit -m "blah blah"  git push origin master$         and then I pull by $git pull$.  That's without the dollar signs

Comment: Try "git pull --rebase" and please share the result if there is an error

Comment: You can get behind your own branch by making changes on GitHub directly. (I do this all the time when editing .md files in the browser.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard And this may likely be the explanation.

Comment: @volatilevar I tried that and got the same error.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I actually did make some minor changes on the website directly.  What can I do now?

Comment: If you did make a change directly to your github and you don't have too many changes to push, you can probably copy your directory/files and put elsewhere, git stash what you have locally, then do a git pull, copy and paste what you had, then push it to github.

Comment: @bloomers How could `git pull --rebase` give the same exact error?  You're not pushing.  Either `git pull origin master` or `git pull --rebase origin master` should resolve your problem.

Comment: Could you please try "git pull --rebase origin master"

Comment: @applecrusher So I should copy the files that I've updated on my machine in another file, cd to the original directory, type "git stash", then "git pull", and then copy the files from the other folder, and push?  What exactly does "git stash" do?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It gave me the same error as when I tried to pull

Comment: @volatilevar I did that.  I got this: CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in index.html
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0002 newest portfolio
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".

Comment: git stash puts away/stashes locally the changes you made locally to your computer, to avoid conflicts with pulls. That way you should be able to pull without any overriding, merges, conflicts, etc. Then you just copy over back to the original directory , now that you have a non-conflicting branch, your changes you made locally and then you should be able to push without conflict.

Comment: @applecrusher  I typed "git stash".  It returned the following:     index.html: needs merge
    index.html: needs merge
    index.html: unmerged (7a7....6b)
    index.html: unmerged (1f03b....4d)
    index.html: unmerged (de0c....48)
    fatal: git-write-tree: error building trees
    Cannot save the current index state

Comment: You can do "git rebase --abort" and then do "git stash" as @applecrusher said

Comment: @applecrusher  What does that do?

Comment: what does git stash do? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash
what does the git rebase --abort do? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase It should cancel any rebase you are doing. Did rebase first then try to stash? That might be causing the issue. using git rebase --abort should then doing git stash should help.

Comment: If you are spending a lot of time on this and don't get your answer soon. Another thing you could do is clone it again on a clean and empty directory and then copy over the latest changes/files. Just a thought if you are really struggling still.

Comment: @applecrusher I copied the one file to a different folder, did "git rebase --abort".  It told me: "No rebase in progress?"  Then I hit "git stash" ; it told me: "No local changes to save".  Then I hit "git pull" and it once again told me: "There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with."

Comment: @applecrusher If I clone, will I still be able to push?  I feel like I've tried that before and it wouldn't let me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, it sounds like you have made a mess here that you will have to clean up one way or another.  However, the immediate solution to the immediate problem:

> ```
> There is no tracking information for the current branch.
> ```

is the one Git is telling you to do:

> ```
> git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
> ```

In particular, you obviously want `origin/master` set as the upstream for `master`:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

Now all three commands—`git pull`,<sup>1</sup> `git merge`, and `git rebase`—will know that you want to keep your `master` in sync with your Git's memory of some other Git's `master`.

Your Git, at certain points (when you tell it to), connects to `origin`, finds out what *they* have in *their* master, brings over anything required, and sets *your* `origin/master` to remember this.  The main point of contact is you running `git fetch` or `git fetch origin` (if you leave out the `origin`, Git figures out which remote you mean to use, or guesses `origin` if all else fails).

Once you have the updated memory, you can compare what you have (your `master`) to what your Git remembers that they have (your `origin/master`).  If it's time to do so, you can `git merge` or `git rebase` your master, to merge or rebase using (your memory of) theirs.

You may get merge conflicts!  These are normal: they just mean that *you* changed something in some file, and *they* (whoever they are) changed something in the *same* file, and both of you touched the same *lines* of that file, but you and they did *different things* to the lines.  Git doesn't know whether you're smarter than they are, or they are smarter than you are, or what.  It just puts *both* changes into your file and makes you clean up the mess.  You must now edit the conflicting file(s), put the *right* lines into them, and save them back to the work-tree; then `git add` and `git commit` the final results of all the merging.

(If you use `git rebase` instead of `git merge`, you will still get merge conflicts, but once you have resolved them and `git add`-ed the files, you should run `git rebase --continue` instead of `git commit`.  See many other SO questions and answers on merge and rebase.)

---

I recommend avoiding `git pull` because it does too much: it first runs `git fetch` for you, then runs `git merge` for you.  (Or it runs `git rebase` for you instead of `git merge`, if you tell it so.)  Now, it's true that after `git fetch`, you very often want to run one of these other two commands ... but you don't necessarily want to run it *right away*.  And, you have *two* commands to try: how do you know which one you want?  *And* if things go wrong—which they do—how do you know which command's help to look for?  If *you* run the merge or rebase yourself, you have the answers to all of these.  This is why I say: forget about `git pull`, just stick with `git fetch` and whichever other second command you prefer.